How to change all boolean values in a list at once
I have a boolean list consist of True and False as follows. I want to know how to change all the values ​​in a list to True or False at once.
my_list = [ False, True, False ]
print(my_list)

my_list[:] = True

The last line throws an exception error, which is not what I expected.

my_list = [False, True, False]

my_list[:] = [True] * len(my_list)

print(my_list)

